# What is the matter when I installing spark-python on CentOS

Tags: python, apache-spark, cloudera

I have a problem installing spark-python on CentOS.
When I installed it using `yum install spark-python`, I get the following error message.

> Error: Package: spark-python-1.6.0+cdh5.9.0+229-1.cdh5.9.0.p0.30.el5.noarch (cloudera-cdh5)
>              Requires: python26
>
> You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
>
> You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest

I already installed other spark packages (spark-master, spark-worker...) but it only occurred installing spark-python.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: The package you are installing ( spark-python-1.6.0+cdh5.9.0+229-1.cdh5.9.0.p0.30.el5.noarch) has a dependency on python 2.6 which is very old version of python. Chances are you have python 2.7 or 3.x, thus the dependency is not satisfied. Try running `which python` and `python --version` and add the output to the question.

Comment: Thank you ventsyv.
The result of which python is below :
/bin/python 
adn the result of python --version is below :
Python 2.7.5
According to your response, I need to downgrade my python version to use the spark-python? 

Best regards,
Leo Kim

Answer (score 0):

You are installing spark Python 1.6 which depends on Python 2.6
I think the current stable version is 2.x and the package for that is pyspark. Try installing that. It might require Python 3.0 but thats easy enough to install.
You'll probably need to reinstall the other spark packages as well to make sure they are the right version.

Answer (score 0):

you have to install python (2.6 version) first:

```
sudo yum install python26
```